# How do you use webpack-merge and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-merge

I have been trying to make a webpack config for a react based app, it was working before I started using webpack-merge and had the single webpack.config.js file. I have done a lot of reading and I have not been able to find a solution and was wondering if there is a way for me to have a split webpack config.

Any help would be much appreciated!

The error I am getting is:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <App title={title} />,
|     document.getElementById('app')
| );

webpack 5.19.0 compiled with 1 error in 17 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

My webpack config files:
**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.js'),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['@babel-loader'], 
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.html')
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './dist'),
        hot: true,
    },
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
    const envConfig = require(`./webpack.${env}.js`);

    return merge(commonConfig, envConfig);
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

My other files: 
**App.js**

```
import React from "react";

const App = ({ title }) => 
    <div>{title}</div>;

export default App;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='app'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "../App";


ReactDOM.render(
    <App title={title} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);

module.hot.accept();
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config build-utils/webpack.dev.js --env env=dev",
    "build": "webpack --config build-utils/webpack.prod.js --env env=prod",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "webpack": "^5.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
```